# Python Gmail API Pipfile Configuration

Tags: python-3.x, gmail

When I try to install the google standard packages for accessing the gmail API in a pipenv instance, I keep getting a pylance error in my Python script that does not recognize the various google packages that are supposed to be installed by default.

My current TOML file looks like the following

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
google-auth = "*"
google-auth-oauthlib = "*"
google-auth-httplib2 = "*"
google-api-python-client = "*"
urllib3 = "<2.0.0"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"your text
```

My python quickstart script looks like this:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly']

# The ID of a sample document.
DOCUMENT_ID = '195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE'


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
        document = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()

        print('The title of the document is: {}'.format(document.get('title')))
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

I originally was having issues with the urllib3 dependency and added a specific value to ensure it was the right version.  Now I cannot locate what might be causing the dependency issues for the remaining packages and could not locate a requirements.txt or pipfile for the other packages to specify what might be causing the issue.  The python environment is only supposed to be above 3.7 from what I read and I tried a variety of python versions starting from 3.9 and up to 3.11.1.

I'm sure that I'm just missing something silly.  I'm a bit new to all of this so any help would be welcome.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the error?

Comment: I answered my own question below.  Basically I was getting the dependency error "not found" for packages in the shell because the new shell wasn't in line with the python interpreter for that shell.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is so silly, but the answer is that I had to manually select the python interpreter that lives inside of my pipenv instance.  Basically I was using a global version of the python install.  Once I selected the python version inside my virtual environment, it finds all the dependencies.